# Normal Complement to a Sylow $2$-subgroup in a group of order $4$ mod $8$.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

For a group of order $n$ congruent to $4$ mod $8$, the Sylow $2$-subgroup has order $4$, and hence is either cyclic, or elementary abelian.

In the first case (cyclic Sylow) we know that there is a normal complement, and clearly in the other case there may not be. An example of course is the alternating group $A_5$, or any of the other simple groups of order $4$ mod $8$. But all of the simple groups of that size $3$ divides the order of the group.

Is it possible that if $3$ does not divide the order of the group, then we do get a normal complement? Does anyone have a counter example, or a reference. 
Edit: Thanks for the hints. Burnsides theorem works fine if the sylow 2 group is cyclic, but it needs help if the sylow 2 subgroup is the non-cyclic group of order 4. That is the reason for the hypothesis that 3 does not divide the order of the group. As of now  I do not see how to apply this. 
As pointed out below by DH and JL, the key is that the action of the normalizer N of the sylow subgroup on itself gives a homomorphism to the automorphism group of C_2 x C_2, which is S3. The kernel of this homomorphism is the center of N, so N/Center(N) injects into S3.  But N has no elements of order 3, since G doesn’t.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, and as Andreas Caranti points out, you can prove it using Burnside's Transfer Theorem.

Comment: To spell it out: the automorphism group of $C_2\times C_2$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** take a look at [Burnside's normal $p$-complement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_p-complement#Burnside_normal_p-complement_theorem).